How to categorise the group based on the Yes No answer in Excel
I am newbie on Excel and have created a survey form and would like to analyse which type of learning style (I.e. four types) belongs to the respondent based on his choices after answering list of questions.
In the collected raw data, which formula I can use ? Thank you so much !
enter image description here
I would like to have the formula to generate which type of the learning style “rank” the “highest score) for each respondent feedback

Can you show us your raw data in Excel itself? I might have an idea on how to get this done, but I have no clue on where you want automated and manual data inputted.
